# Using memcpy from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, memcpy, unsafe

I was writing a streaming class between arduino and c#. I wrote it for arduino using c++ and it worked like a charm. Now, i am trying to migrate my code to work over c#.

```
Stream::reciveObj(Stream &str, void* ptr, unsigned int Size)
{
 char data[objSize]; //Create a tmp array
 stream.readBytes(data, objSize); //Read bytes
 memcpy(ptr, data, objSize); //Copy into struct
}
```

Now i want to migrate that code to c#

```
unsafe public static void recieveObj(SerialPort str, void* ptr, uint Size)
{
 char[] data = new char[Size];
 str.Read(data, 0, (int)Size);
 // memcpy(ptr, data, objSize); //Copy into struct
}
```

how can i make a memcpy from array to void* in c#

thanks

Comment: How to [copy an array in C#/.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be easy to find if you just search a little.

Comment: This way doesn't work :D i searched a lot !!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to use memcpy in c#, shamelesly borrowed [here](http://www.abstractpath.com/2009/memcpy-in-c/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
public unsafe class Program
{
 public delegate void MemCpyFunction(void *des, void *src, uint bytes);

 private static readonly MemCpyFunction MemCpy;

 static Program()
 {
     var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod
     (
         "MemCpy",
         typeof(void),
         new [] { typeof(void *), typeof(void *), typeof(uint) },
         typeof(Program)
     );

     var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Cpblk);
     ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

     MemCpy = (MemCpyFunction)dynamicMethod
                 .CreateDelegate(typeof(MemCpyFunction));
 }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var point1 = new Point
                  {
                      X = 10,
                      Y = 20
                  };

     var point2 = new Point();

     MemCpy(&point2, &point1, (uint)sizeof(Point));
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Great, but it just copies the same type of objects, i need to copy an array of bytes to *void

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer:
+ @rickythefox

```
 char* charPointer = stackalloc char[(int)objSize];
            for(int i=0; i < (int)objSize ; ++i)
            {
                charPointer[i] = data[i];
            }

            MemCpy(ptr, charPointer, objSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is `System.Buffer.MemoryCopy(...)`. Which is calling pinvoked clr `__Memmove(...)` [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/buffer.cs,503). Which suggests it is able to handle overlapping blocks.
Then...
Microsoft quite lately released a NuGet Package: 
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)

This package specifically, contains a static class under same name and namespace which contains 
`CopyBlock(void* dest, void* src, uint byteCount)` and 
`CopyBlockUnaligned(...)` methods.
Whole class contains a lot of cool helper methods.
[Here is the src in IL](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il). It shows that these methods are using `cpblk` opcode which (according to spec) handles overlapping blocks as undefined behavior.